# ruby 2.2 , how to display the current content of the file?

Tags: ruby, file-io

in a ruby 2.2. script, I am writing an xml file

```
@filehandle << '<plist version="1.0">'
...
@filehandle << "\n<#{element_name}>"
..
```

during debugging , I would like to display the current content, how can I get it as it's not yet closed, but only cached ... ?
thanks for your suggestions

```
byebug 
@filehandle.class
File
@filehandle
#<File:./AlbumData-new.xml>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute these calls in order to display the content (I assume that the file is opened for reading and writing, i.e., mode is `r+`, `w+` or `a+`)

```
@filehandle.flush # Make sure everything is written to disk
@filehandle.seek(0) # So we can read from the beginning
@filehandle.read # Read everything
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmad ... don't know who down voted it ...  it's answered my question